# Unable to clean recently used items in windows 10

Tags: windows, batch-file

The batch command  `del /s /f /q %userprofile%\Recent\*.*`  doesn't seem to be working. While  `del /s /f /q %USERPROFILE%\appdata\local\temp\*.*`  is working fine.

```
C:\Users\zzzzz\Recent>del /s /f /q %userprofile%\Recent\*.*                        
Could Not Find C:\Users\zzzzz\Recent\*.*
```

The path does exist and I can manually cleanup the directory but the same is not working through given command. The command is run as an administrator too but same error.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Recent files link]

below `%userprofile%` is not a regular folder. The real content is here:

```
%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\
```

where it doesn't have the typical "link" overlay:

[image: Recent files]